# BCS and SharePoint 2010

Tags: bcs

I'm looking to possibly upgrading to the latest version simply because the latest version has BCS integrated with the free version.  A question I have to answer is "Does BCS integrate with Sage Timberline software; specifically the accounting package?"  How can I find the answer to my question OR has someone already done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timberline uses a pervasive database and is only accessible via the ODBC or becoming a 3rd party developer. As a 3rd party developer I can tell you the API is in its infancy.  I guess the only good news I have is products do exist that mirror Timberline to a SQL server.  Perhaps that's a better approach.

Comment: OHHHHH reealaalalllllyyyyyyyyyyyy... Do you have a link?  That would be the best approach for my situation.

Comment: I've rolled my own:
http://blog.coryfoy.com/2005/06/lets-go-crazy-accessing-timberline-pervasive-data-from-a-sql-linked-server/

Or:
http://www.argussoftware.com

Comment: Right after reading this post, I was directed to this exact blog post.  Excellent!  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

The BCS can integrate with any system that can be exposed through SQL or Web Services.

I have a strong preference to use Web Services for any integration so that you have a defined integration point that is easier to reuse.  If Sage Timberline has published web services then you may be able to connect to them from the BCS.  Worst case scenario you can write custom web services against the Timberline API and point the BCS to that.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that you can create custom .NET connectors for the BCS as well instead of going the web service way.